# Characterization of all symplectic form on $\mathbb C^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, symplectic-geometry, vector-spaces

Recall that: a symplectic form is a non-degenerate skew-symmetric $\mathbb R$-bilinear form.

- The only $\mathbb R$-valued symplectic form on $\mathbb C$, $f:\mathbb C\times \mathbb C\rightarrow \mathbb R$, is $f(z,w)=\Im m (z\overline{w})$.
- The only $\mathbb C$-valued  symplectic form on $\mathbb C$, $f:\mathbb C\times \mathbb C\rightarrow \mathbb C$, is $f(z,w)=\alpha \, z\overline{w}; \, \alpha\in \mathbb R$.

I would like know, there is a characterization of all $\mathbb C$-valued symplectic forms on $\mathbb C^2$, $f:\mathbb C^2\times \mathbb C^2\rightarrow \mathbb C$ ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: It depends on whether you mean $\mathbf{R}$-bilinear or $\mathbf{C}$-bilinear. Anyway in both cases, it's not of research level.

Comment: Yes, the $\mathbb R$-bilinear form.

Comment: To clarify: You want a normal form for the skew-symmetric, non-degenerate, $\mathbb{R}$-bilinear maps $f \colon \mathbb{C}^2 \times \mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}$?  Is that the question?

Comment: It's a question of a general description, not a normal form. Anyway the post is wrong, not all $\mathbf{R}$-bilinear symplectic forms $\mathbf{C}\times\mathbf{C}\to\mathbf{C}$ have the specified form.

Comment: @  Jesse Madnick. Yes,  that is the question